# Why do we need to check typeof window in React frameworks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a question that needs to be answered; when I use React with some server-side framework like NextJS, and RemixJS, there are some cases where I need to check the condition `typeof window` variable in the useEffect hook.

As far as I know, the `useEffect` hook always runs on the client side after a component is rendered, so why do we need to check the `typeof window`? What is this check for?

Here is an example code that I used to describe the question:

```js
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isBrowser) {
    return;
  }

  // do something here
}, [isBrowser]);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to check that at all.

Comment: @Terry No, In the server side, if you need to get state from useState() in client side, you need to check typeof window, because `useState()` will run before useEffect is runned. that's an example of the case.

Comment: @Epple But you’re not using `useState` in your example at all. I don’t understand what you’re getting at. `useEffect` is only run on the client and so window is never undefined, hence making the check unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

> Effects only run on the client. They don’t run during server
> rendering.

According to the [React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#caveats).

The hook might run in other non-browser React environments like React Native where this check would make sense.